Spring Cloud gateway rate-limeter with Hazelcast
Tying to implement hazelcast for ratelimit in spring cloud gateway.
This example is working fine for using new hazelcast member.
[1]: https://github.com/o-ardic/springboot-bucket4j-example
But I want to use existing hazelcast cluster member that is already registered to my eureka with name HCAST.
How to acheive this. Sample would be helpful.

I have a pull request that will add bucketj4 support early next year https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/pull/2955

so with this enhancement can we use any cache impl othert han redis? I am looking for a hazelcast one as mentioned above.

achieved this ratelimit with griffing starter dependency. More information at : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79174174/spring-cloud-ratelimit-with-bucket-4j-and-hazelcast]

hazelcast.xml is used to start an hazelcast server. hazelcast-client.xml is used to start a hazelcast client that connects to a cluster. Create a file named hazelcast-client.xml and fill it with client configuration

did this and as mentioned above have resolved the issue.
